# How to get distinct using `OVER(PARTITION BY ...)`

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

How to get distinct using `OVER(PARTITION BY ...)`?

```
SELECT ACCT_TYPE_CD AS entity,
         ACCT_ID AS entity_VAL,
         COUNT (1) AS CNT
    FROM ACCOUNT
GROUP BY ACCT_TYPE_CD, ACCT_ID
  HAVING COUNT (1) > 1;

entity      |entity_val      |cnt |
------------|----------------|----|
EMPID       |1               |3   |
EMPID       |1066            |3   |
```

The same I want using below query, so that I should be able to use this as inner query.

```
select  ACCT_TYPE_CD, ACCT_ID,  COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ACCT_TYPE_CD, ACCT_ID) AS CNT
from ACCOUNT ACCT; 

acct_type_cd |ACCT_ID     |cnt |
-------------|------------|----|
EMPID        |1           |3   |
EMPID        |1           |3   |
EMPID        |1           |3   |
EMPID        |1066        |3   |
EMPID        |1066        |3   |
EMPID        |1066        |3   |
```

Comment: Can you please show what will be the final query ?

Comment: Your second query looks like it should be a simple `GROUP BY` query, if you don't want duplicates (and if your only selecting those columns).

Comment: @Marth - I am not sure what you mean, could you please show in query ?

Comment: If the first query does what you want, then why do you want a different query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select *
from (
    select  acct_type_cd, acct_id, count(*) over(partition by acct_type_cd, acct_id) as cnt
    from account acct
) t
where cnt > 1
```

That is: you can't use window functions in the `where` clause of a query - you need to compute the window count in a subquery, then filter in the outer query.

Alternatively, if you want to generate the same result as the first query using window functions only, then you might be looking for `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select  
        acct_type_cd, 
        acct_id, 
        count(*) over(partition by acct_type_cd, acct_id) as cnt,
        row_number() over(partition by acct_type, acct_id order by acct_type, acct_id) rn
    from account acct
) t
where cnt > 1 and rn = 1
```

That said, I don't really why you would want to do that; using aggregation (as in the first query) is probably always more efficient than two window functions and filtering (as in the second query).

Here is one last option using `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (acct_type_cd, acct_id)
    acct_type_cd, 
    acct_id, 
    count(*) over(partition by acct_type_cd, acct_id) as cnt
from account acct
order by acct_type_cd, acct_id
```

Comment: Nope, this not what I want, I want unique records. I want the result of 1st query from 2nd query as well

Comment: @JeffCook: I don't understand what you mean. Would you please edit your question to show the result that you want?

Comment: Please read it properly. I want output of 1st query from the 2nd query

Comment: Your last query make sense, yes, let me try to see to use in the larger query where I want to use it.